# Django password_reset view, what is link variable for template?

Tags: django, django-templates

According to Django's [password_reset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) view, it

> Allows a user to reset their password
>   by generating a one-time use link that
>   can be used to reset the password, and
>   sending that link to the user's
>   registered e-mail address.

with the email being generated by a user-supplied template. What I can't find is the name of the *link variable* to use in the email-template (and it's not **{{ link }}** :)

In the *django-registration* app, for instance, it's *{{ activation_key }}*.

I even ran *{% debug %}* in my template to look at all the variables, and nothing looked obvious. Also, this is Django 1.2, not the development version.

Update: my template looks like:

```
{{ protocol }}://localhost:8000{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid token=token %}

Click on the link (or copy/paste into your browser), and then you can change your password
```

And gives me the result (in a text file simulating email):

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/confirm/12-2ws-1c60be00955ea4=
a7a62e/

Click on the link (or copy/paste into your browser), and then you can chang=
e your password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the default `password_reset_email.html`

```
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html
```

This is what generates the link:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
```

**edit:**

for version 1.2:

```
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/branches/releases/1.2.X/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html?rev=15606
```

which doesn't quote the view.

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid token=token %}
```

There is a note about this revision stating:

Revision 12889, 617 bytes checked in by russellm, 13 months ago (diff)

> Fixed #12945 -- Corrected the parsing
>   of arguments in {% url %} when the
>   argument list has spaces between
>   commas. This is a revised version of
>   r12503, which was a fix for #12072.
>   Thanks to SmileyChris? for the patch,
>   and to dmoisset for finding all the
>   places in the docs that the old style
>   syntax was used.

Here is a note about changes with the url tag:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi

Comment: That *almost* works - but includes an equals-sign/space about half a dozen chars before the end. Is there some parameter that is causing it to break the line? Or any idea how to fix it?

Comment: is it because of autoescaping? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape the original template turns off autoescaping.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's auto-escaping, or something else to do with line length. For instance, I have another line "click on the link... change your password" which gets shorted to "chang= " "e your password" on the next line. Hope that's clear.

Comment: can you edit your original post to include what your template looks like and what you are getting when you view source your page.

Comment: Unless you see something obvious, I may post that issue as a separate Question. It seems unrelated to constructing an activation link, and more about how templates generate text files.

Comment: ya i'm not exactly sure i've never seen anything like that before but im looking around. That might be an interesting question in itself. I'll keep digging but feel free to post it into another question if it isn't already asked on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a url reverse on the 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' view as shown in the [default email](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html).

Comment: That looks very interesting, but I'm having problems getting the parameters working. I should note that I'm using V 1.2, and that link is for the development version - any idea how 1.2 would do it?

Comment: Thanks, but mostly got it working now. Your answer is certainly on the right track (and I upvoted it), but the other one was a bit more complete.